# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

in a Dart class, I am trying to retrieve the position of the rider from the **Firebase Realtime ** Database. but keep getting the error.

**Note: I am following a 2-year-old tutorial but all my SDK is up to date. AS a result, I might not know the new format. I would appreciate any help on this.**

The Code :

```
void FetchRideInfo(String rideID) {
    DatabaseReference rideRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('rideRequest/$rideID');

    rideRef.once().then((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
      if (databaseEvent.snapshot.value != null) {
        double pickupLat = double.parse(
            databaseEvent.snapshot.value['location']['latitude'].toString()); /error here
      }
    });
  }
```

The error on ['location'] is

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.
```

[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

`databaseEvent` is a property with type object. An indexer cannot be called on an object. In order to use it, you need to first cast it.

You need to use the cast operator `as`. The following should work:

```dart
double pickupLat = double.parse((databaseEvent.snapshot.value as List)['location']['latitude']);
```

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

This error is now showing on ['location']